# JAVA Inversion of multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

How can I achieve this with a for loop?

(simplified version of what i want to do)>

FROM

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

TO

1 4 7

2 5 8

3 6 9

```
        final int F = 5;
        final int C = 5;
        int f, c, aux = 0;

        int t[][] = new int[F][C];

        for (f = 0; f < F; f++) {
            for (c = 0; c < C; c++) {
                t[f][c] = (int) (Math.random() * 50 - 50);                                           
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Before inversion: ");   

        for (f = 0; f < F; f++) {
            for (c = 0; c < C; c++) {

                System.out.printf("%2d  ", t[f][c]);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");

        }
        System.out.println("After inversion: "); 

        for (f = 1; f < F / 2; f++) {
            for (c = 0; c < C; c++) {   
                aux = t[f][f-1];              
                t[f][f-1] = t[f - 1][f];
                t[f - 1][f] = aux;
            }
        }
```

Rest of code is printing the new array
Also I need some help with the Math.random. It isn't working as intended, the values it gives should range from -50 to 50.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? Have you debugged your code at all? If not, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some suggestions to get you started.

Comment: As for `Math.random`. You want 100 values, so you need to do `(int) (Math.random() * 100 - 50)`

Comment: I think you are trying to transpose the matrix. Inverting a matrix is something different.